# Check when a form-field component is loaded in React based module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, liferay, liferay-7

I've created a Liferay **form-field** module based on React.

I want to manipulate the component with Javascript but as the code fires when DOM is ready, but the component isn't, the code doesn't work.

The problem is that I'm trying to get a DOM element this way:

```
document.querySelector(".slider-divisor")
```

I've tried putting this line in many places of the JS file (resources/META-INF/resources/slider-form-field.es.js) but the result is always *null*.

I've found a solution using *setInterval* that checks when the component 'appears' in the DOM. Then, the code is executed and *setInterval* stops, but I want to know if exists a way to check an event when component is loaded to execute my code instead use *setinterval*.

This is command I've used to create the module:

```
blade create -t form-field -c SliderFormField --js-framework react -p com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.form.field.type.slider slider-form-field
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ReactDom.render` takes an extra parameter callback, that is called when the root element is mounted.

Comment: There isn't any ReactDom.render call in the file. You can view the code here: https://res.cloudinary.com/carlosdurannetcloud/image/upload/v1649331874/snippets/JS_render_file_from_Liferay_form-file_module_yhzsbi.png